# Why do we use the massive dirac fermion model for MoS2?

Tags: condensed-matter, graphene, tight-binding

I can derive the massive Dirac fermion Hamiltonian using a tight binding model of graphene with a staggered sublattice potential, but many (including [Xiao et al, PRL 2012](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.108.196802)) use this model for MoS2 as well, which I do not understand.  In the paper they describe that their basis is made of two d-states on the Mo atoms, and show nearest neighbor vectors going from a central Mo atom to each adjacent Mo atom, not regarding the S sites at all.  So, taking this basis we have a one atom trigonal lattice, not a two atom basis like graphene.

So, when I work out the phase factors in the tight binding model I always end up with things like 
$$(exp(i k\cdot r_1) + exp(-i k\cdot r_1) + exp(i k\cdot r_2) \\\qquad\qquad+ exp(-i k\cdot r_2) + exp(i k.r_3) + exp(-i k\cdot r_3))$$
for each term.  Unlike the graphene model, this is a real valued function.  So all of the matrix elements of the hamiltonian become real.  I cant see how that can be reduced into the massive dirac model.

Put another way, in the graphene model with staggered sublattice potential there are only three neighbors which are all on the other sub lattice, call them $r_1, r_2$ and $r_3$. On the MoS2 model we have six neighbors with $r_1, r_2, r_3, -r_1, -r_2$ and $-r_3$ vectors. While they have the same hexagonal reciprocal lattice, it still seems like that difference in symmetry is changing my tight-binding model and making it significantly different from the graphene model and therefor different from the massive Dirac model.

Any help on where I am going wrong conceptually would be appreciated, or any advise about another way to think about why this model is applicable without re-doing the tight binding model.

Comment: They mentioned two d-states on the Mo, but your tight binding model only consider a single state on Mo, I think that is the why you can not obtain a Dirac model (which would require at least two states in 2D).

Comment: @EverettYou I think you are right, I was trying to use two states on the Mo atoms, but I was assuming they were isotropic.  Now I think that the 'symmetry requirements' mentioned in the paper I cited referr to the actual anisotropy in the XY plane of the states chosen for the valence band. Thanks.